# ffmpeg image sequence specify input framerate

Tags: input, ffmpeg, frame-rate

I am trying to set the input framerate of a sequence of images (many folders):

if I am working with a single image sequence everything works properly:

`ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i folder01/img%05d.jpeg -filter:v "crop=640:360" -r 30 outfilm.mp4`

then, because I have more folders (and I was unable to get the -i concat:filesequence1|filesequence2 working) I tried to use:

`ffmpeg -framerate 30 -f concat -safe 0 -i filelist.txt -filter:v "crop=640:360" -r 30 outfilm.mp4`

but I receive an error:

`Option framerate not found.`

then if I omit the `-framerate 30`, everything runs smoothly, but ffmpeg defaults to a 25 fps value for the input image sequences.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: If you check the manual, the `-framerate` option is only valid for the `image2` demuxer. When you're using `-f concat`, you're using another demuxer (the `concat` demuxer), which does not support that option.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -r 30 -i filelist.txt -filter:v "crop=640:360" -r 30 outfilm.mp4
```

When `-r` is used as an input option, it generates new timestamps at the given rate and sets that as the input framerate.

Comment: Well noted @Mulvya, I originally missed this because I placed the `-r 30` before the `-f concat`. Thank you!

Comment: **Why do so many people use filelist.txt etc? This is how I converted a series of images named pic_001.png to whatever end (it automatically detects it).** Just specify a file pattern, and a framerate with `-r` (mine is 0.25 meaning each image shows for 4 seconds). Here's the command: `ffmpeg -r 0.25 -i "pic_%03d.png" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset veryslow output.mp4`